# Cannot insert duplicate key error message for update query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update data using this update query....not inserting. but i am getting this error message. How to fix this

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Procedure
>   BF_TR_BUDCONTRACTS_HISTORY_INSERTUPDATE, Line 67 Violation of UNIQUE
>   KEY constraint 'UK_BudContractHis'. Cannot insert duplicate key in
>   object 'dbo.BUDCONTRACTS_HISTORY'. The duplicate key value is (10567,
>   4377, 228, 1). The statement has been terminated.

```
Update BUDCONTRACTS
 set    BUDCONTRACTS.VERSIONID = 1
       ,BUDCONTRACTS.STATUSID = 1
       ,BUDCONTRACTS.ImportedRecord = 1
       ,BUDCONTRACTS.CUSTOMERID = BCUST.CustomerID
       ,BUDCONTRACTS.LastModifiedUserID = 'Import'
       ,BUDCONTRACTS.LASTMODIFIEDDATETIME = GETDATE()
FROM BUDCONTRACTS BCON
INNER JOIN External_Blk_Itm_Contracts EBIC WITH(NOLOCK) ON BCON.ContractName = EBIC.ContractName  AND EBIC.ContractName = '00-000'
INNER JOIN BUDTERMINALS BT WITH(NOLOCK) ON BT.MBFTERMINALNAME = EBIC.TerminalName AND BT.TERMINALID = BCON.TERMINALID
INNER JOIN BudCustomers BCUST WITH(NOLOCK) ON BCUST.LegalName = EBIC.CustomerName AND BCUST.CustomerID = BCON.CUSTOMERID 
AND (
   (BCON.STATUSID <> 1) 
OR (BCON.ImportedRecord <> 1) 
OR (ISNULL(BCON.CUSTOMERID,'') <> ISNULL(BCUST.CustomerID,'')
))
```

Comment: You're probably trying to update one of the key columns to a value that already exists in the table.

Comment: The table BUDCONTRACTS_HISTORY is not involved in your update command. Is this the entirely procedure code? Is there any trigger for the table BUDCONTRACTS?

Comment: there is unqiue key constraint on customerid column

Comment: Again with the NOLOCK hints on an update? That is only one of the major issues here. You are using an update from but you are updating the table. You need to update the alias instead because sometimes it will get things wrong and update incorrect rows. You also should not use the table or alias name in the list of set predicates because you can only update one table at a time anyway. Please for the sake of your data, your company and your system get those NOLOCKs out of your queries. They have a purpose but using them all the time is a nightmare.

Comment: @SeanLange, can you post one sample correcting my above query so that i can follow the same pattern for my future queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better way to write this update.

```
Update BCON
set VERSIONID = 1
    , STATUSID = 1
    , ImportedRecord = 1
    , CUSTOMERID = BCUST.CustomerID
    , LastModifiedUserID = 'Import'
    , LASTMODIFIEDDATETIME = GETDATE()
FROM BUDCONTRACTS BCON
INNER JOIN External_Blk_Itm_Contracts EBIC ON BCON.ContractName = EBIC.ContractName  AND EBIC.ContractName = '00-000'
INNER JOIN BUDTERMINALS BT ON BT.MBFTERMINALNAME = EBIC.TerminalName AND BT.TERMINALID = BCON.TERMINALID
INNER JOIN BudCustomers BCUST ON BCUST.LegalName = EBIC.CustomerName AND BCUST.CustomerID = BCON.CUSTOMERID 
AND 
(
    BCON.STATUSID <> 1
    OR
    BCON.ImportedRecord <> 1
) 
--OR ISNULL(BCON.CUSTOMERID,'') <> ISNULL(BCUST.CustomerID,'' This is pointless here because you already joined where these values are equal
```

Now for the actual issue. You are not referencing dbo.BUDCONTRACTS_HISTORY in this query so it is obvious there is an UPDATE trigger on BUDCONTACTS. That is where the problem is happening. It is probably trying to insert a row into the history table but there is already a row with the key value so it is unable to insert that row. If you can post the trigger code and the table definition for dbo.BUDCONTRACTS_HISTORY we can help you straighten out the trigger.

Comment: Thanks @Sean Lange understand that

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it turned out I didn't have enough keys in the update statement to only update 1 record when I ran the query it returned more than 1 row and the update failed. This was good as I had changed the clustered index for the extra field.